# Stopping recursive CTE with a guard

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, infinite-loop

I have the following hierarchical data going from source to destination and i would like to stop when a reference to an existing source appears

```
create table #temp (source int, destination int);
insert into #temp values (1,3), (3,7), (7,9), (9,1);

WITH cte (Source, Destination, Level, Sources)
AS 
(
    SELECT Source, Destination, 0 AS Level, CAST(Source AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' AS Sources
    FROM #temp 
    WHERE [Source] = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.[Source], t.Destination, cte.[Level] + 1, cte.Sources + CAST(t.Source AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ','
    FROM #temp t        
        INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Destination = t.[Source] AND (CAST(t.Destination AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' NOT LIKE '%' + cte.Sources + '%')
)
select * from cte

drop table #temp;
```

however i still get the max recursion error when running this. how should i write the guard clause properly? What I do want is the first 3 results.

Comment: A `where` clause in the second part of the CTE usually does the trick. Something like `where cte.[Level] < 2` (should give 3 results: levels 0, 1, and 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, in the recursive member of the CTE:

```
INNER JOIN cte 
    ON  cte.Destination = t.[Source] 
    AND (CAST(t.Destination AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' NOT LIKE '%' + cte.Sources + '%')
```

You have the `LIKE` operands the wrong way around. Instead:

```
INNER JOIN cte 
    ON cte.Destination = t.[Source] 
    AND cte.Sources NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', t.Destination, '%')
```

That is: the destination should be belong to the list of sources that were already visited. Note that using `CONCAT()` forces the conversion of the number to a string, which shortens the expression.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3799b49fee712a3e6490abb180ca2d0)**

Answer (score 2):

Add a `where` clause to the recursive part of the CTE.

```
create table #temp (source int, destination int);
insert into #temp values (1,3), (3,7), (7,9), (9,1);

WITH cte (Source, Destination, Level, Sources)
AS 
(
    SELECT Source, Destination, 0 AS Level, CAST(Source AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' AS Sources
    FROM #temp 
    WHERE [Source] = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.[Source], t.Destination, cte.[Level] + 1, cte.Sources + CAST(t.Source AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ','
    FROM #temp t        
        INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Destination = t.[Source] AND (CAST(t.Destination AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' NOT LIKE '%' + cte.Sources + '%')
    where cte.Level < 2 -- stop after 3 levels (0,1,2)
)
select * from cte

drop table #temp;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=923698453b953cea71c890311034d598)